# Running raw aggregation query of mongo in spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am creating an app where user can type any query in mongo and he should get the results.

Problem is i am not able to find any method which support this aggregation query execution(I am done with all other type of queries like find).

I am running this app in spring,Hibertrnate and using mongoTemplate.

Please guide me how can i proceed?

Comment: Please take a look here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation

Comment: @samiles user can type any type of aggregation so what i want is that any type of script through which i can execute any mongo shell query

Comment: @Mukeshkumar Did you find any solution?